# Dplyr: Capture the output of lazy query

Tags: r, dplyr

When querying SQL table (local SQLite) using dplyr/dbplyr I get the result of the query printed into the console. But when I save the query as a object (list) and try to access these values using $, R returns a NULL.

You can pull the results using collect(), but this adds "unnecessary" step and adds up time to shinyapp loading. If the table is small, it is in fact quicker to pull the whole table and summarize it on R side (see the results of microbenchmark), which sounds quite weird.

```
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
library(DBI)

#create small table of dates, write into existing db
dates = tibble(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-08-22"), as.Date(today()), by = "day")) 
con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), dbname = "training_dash_db", user = "root", password = "", host = 'localhost')
dbWriteTable(con, value = dates, name = "dates", overwrite=TRUE)
dates_table =  tbl(con, "dates")

microbenchmark(r1 = dates_table %>% summarise(min_date = min(date), max_date = max(date)),
               r2 = dates_table %>% summarise(min_date = min(date), max_date = max(date)) %>% collect(),
               r3 = dates_table %>% collect() %>% summarise(min_date = min(date), max_date = max(date)))

Unit: milliseconds
 expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq     max neval cld
   r1  1.5715  1.67225  1.838789  1.72395  1.8077  8.2187   100 a  
   r2 11.7454 12.08405 12.834115 12.33320 13.0451 28.8554   100   c
   r3  3.2547  3.37535  3.627246  3.47065  3.6994  9.6337   100  b
```

I know that we are still talking in miliseconds range, but it is quite unintuitive. 
(1) Is there a way how to capture the output of the query that gets printed into the console and 
(2) what might be the cause of slowdown here?

Comment: Have you tried `capture.output()`?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this is paradoxically more time-expensive, than all other solutions. I'll default to collect() method because of the clarity and simplicity.